# Possible to style a select slider with JS or JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't find way to style a scrollbar of drop down menu, all solutions are only for DIVs but not for  elements. I have tried all JavaScript and jQuery plugins but unsuccessful.

You can see the issue in question here (http://liquor.com/asp-test) - click the drop down under Type of Alcohol and you'll see the scrollbar I wish to style.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, except in IE, unless you emulate a drop down menu using a DIV as you've already mentioned.  Scrollbars are considered part of the browser chrome.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like youre curently using a DIV to mimic the stanrd select list functionality so any plugin that works on a DIV should work on your current implementation. I have use jScrollpane for this in the past and it tends to work well.

If you want to style the drop down itself using the stadard browser/OS generated control i think you may be out of luck there for anything beyond the most basic. Everything else is non-crossbrowser and differs in the level of customization.

Comment: i have tired with jScrollpane with no such luck.

Comment: yes but the divs I can not use for scrolling , for jQuery scroll nee static  div , my divs are created dinamically and natural scrollbar does not allow to jQuery works.
In one word they don't work with each other

Comment: Are you sure, HollerTrain? The example on jScrollPane's site shows dynamically loaded content, and looks like it would work just fine for dynamically-created elements: http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/ajax_example.html

Comment: Look at this link and you will understand where need to add scroll styling and what is problem.
http://www.profprojects.com/select/select.php

Comment: no i know wht youre saying you creating the div on the fly when you determine that its a "mimic select" widget so you can call jScollpane until after this div is created. Assuming im correct you just need to work in using a callback or directly firing the jscrollpane initialization after you transfrom-to/append this special div. I dont know if the plugin youre using supports this though. You may need to modify it, use a different plugin, or write your own in order to do this.